# Error while trying to archive

Tags: ios, xcode

It builds and runs fine on simulator. However, fails when I try to archive.

Error:

> Blockquote
>
> /Users/vatsalshah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dekkho-dilsoelrnclgkxdfmpzdtxdvyhde/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Dekkho/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Dekkho.build/Release-iphoneos/Dekkho.build/Script-EDD4C8551ECC46F5004B3491.sh: line 2: : command not found
> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127

Xcode Version - Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)
Language - Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

When archiving "enable bitcode" checkbox is checked by default. Uncheck it and retry.